# How to register DataTemplate in net MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

In Xamarin we were able to register to take a ViewModel first approach by registring a View and ViewModel in a ResourceDictionary

```cs
public class LoginViewModel
{
    public string Title{get;set;}
}
```

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"                        
                    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:AppVerse.Jewel.NavigationModule.Views"
                    xmlns:viewModels="clr-amespace:AppVerse.Jewel.NavigationModule.ViewModels"
                    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:AppVerse.Jewel.Entities;assembly=AppVerse.Jewel.Entities">
    
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:LoginViewModel}">
        <views:LoginView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This allowed us to have a bind viewmodels and expect the registered view.

I cant find something similar in .Net MAUI. If not how can we do something similar here

Comment: Because there is not something similar in .Net MAUI

Comment: so whats the sugested way to maintain loose coupling between View and ViewModels

Comment: [Prism Maui Navigation](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/maui/navigation/page-navigation.html). This is based on a URI; it uses page *names*, and Maui's DI service to fetch the corresponding page instance. So your code uses a string, rather than a direct reference to the page type. OR see [Prism Maui Navigation Builder](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/maui/navigation/navigation-builder.html) for viewmodel-first navigation.

Comment: In WPF we were able to bind models/viewmodels and could expect WPF to find the respective view/controls etc via data template registration in resource dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, are you want the [Stand-alone resource dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/resource-dictionaries#stand-alone-resource-dictionaries), right?

To create a stand-alone `ResourceDictionary`, add a new `ResourceDictionary` file to the project with the .NET MAUI `ResourceDictionary` (XAML) item template and delete its code-behind file. Then, in the XAML file remove the `x:Class` attribute from the `ResourceDictionary` tag near the start of the file. In addition, add `<?xaml-comp compile="true" ?>` after the XML header to ensure that the XAML will be compiled.

The following XAML example shows a stand-alone ResourceDictionary named `MyResourceDictionary.xaml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xaml-comp compile="true" ?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PersonDataTemplate">
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid RowSpacing="6"
                  ColumnSpacing="6">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                       TextColor="{StaticResource NormalTextColor}"
                       FontAttributes="Bold" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Age}"
                       TextColor="{StaticResource NormalTextColor}" />
                <Label Grid.Column="2"
                       Text="{Binding Location}"
                       TextColor="{StaticResource NormalTextColor}"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
            </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: In WPF we were able to bind models/viewmodels and could expect WPF to find the respective view/controls etc via data template registration in resource dictionary.  I'm looking for a similar setup

Comment: `whats the sugested way to maintain loose coupling between View and ViewModels` Sorry,there is not something similar in .Net MAUI. We need to set `BindContext` for the  view.